# Turn off Guvcview filename incrementation

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, webcam

The guvcview command is automatically incrementing the output filename.

Here is the command I am using:

```
 guvcview -d /dev/video1 --no_display -r 1 -f yuyv -s 2592x1944 -i capture.jpeg -c 2 --exit_on_close
```

The output file names are:

capture-0.jpeg

capture-1.jpeg

capture-2.jpeg

etc...

How can I make this not increment? I want a static filename (capture.jpeg) that is overwritten each time. I can do this from the GUI by clicking the "capture" button, but I need to be able to do this from the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

There should be a file named `.guvcviewrc` in your home directory. In it there's a line `image_inc=1`. Changing it to `image_inc=0` solved the problem for me.

Comment: The configuration file is saved in `~/.config/guvcview/video0` with Ubuntu 14.04 (and the webcam is mapped to `video0`).

Comment: This is **not** working now. `image_inc=0` only helps in setting next file and is not turning of file name incrementation.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure there is no way to accomplish this without outside help from a bash script or something akin to that.

My solution is to edit the timers.c file in the guvcview source.

I removed line 109: "global->image_inc = global->image_picn;"

Removal of this line prevents guvcview from auto-incrementing the filename when set on a timer.

I then recompiled guvcview, and now it is working perfectly!